# Crystal Reports Show Only The last Column

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to display a Table in crystal reports but its show only the last column, this is my code :

```
Try
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim id As Integer = 1
        Dim Report1 As New PrintStockReport
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata( _
              "SELECT StockTable.StockRef, StockTable.StockCat FROM StockTable;")

        
        'Report1.SetDataSource(dt)
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Report1.SetParameterValue("StockID", id)
            Report1.SetParameterValue("StockRef", dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString)
            Report1.SetParameterValue("StockCat", dt.Rows(i)(1).ToString)
            id += 1
        Next
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

but, when I set the `Datasource` its show `" the report has no tables"`, can anyone explain to me why I get this issue? thanks

```
Report1.SetDataSource(dt)
```

Comment: Can you describe the design of your report?  Are you using Parameter Fields to display the data?  That "For Next" loop is part of the problem for sure, but in order to help you fix the problem correctly I need to know more about the report design.  That loop is basically assigning data from a single row in your datatable to the report as Parameter Fields.  Each iteration of the loop discards the data from the previous iteration, so at the end, only the last record remains.

Comment: at first thanks for your explain, yep sure im using parameter fields and i put them in details section to make a table that contain my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets get your VB code fixed.  Remove the For/Next loop completely, and then uncomment the line above it.  Your code should now look like this:

```
    Try
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim id As Integer = 1
        Dim Report1 As New PrintStockReport
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata( _
              "SELECT StockTable.StockRef, StockTable.StockCat FROM StockTable;")

        
        Report1.SetDataSource(dt)
        
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This will properly bind your datatable to the Report1 object as a data source.  Now you need to fix your report in the designer by removing the parameter fields from the report.  Parameter Fields are only used when you need the user to pass input into the report at runtime.  For example, if I were making a report that shows data for a single financial period to the user and I want it to be flexible enough to work with any period, I would use a Parameter Field to ask the user to provide the period as input when the report is executed.  If you look at the Field Explorer in your report designer you should see "Database Fields".  When expanded this should show you the table or tables that are defined as the report's database.  Expanding a table will then show you the list of fields available to the report.  Drag the fields you want displayed on your report to the section where they should appear.

Once this is done, your report should work.  This assumes you have your database defined within the database expert in the report designer though.

Comment: thanks for answer and explain, i have a question about the "Database Fields" i cant fount the table i defind in my code as Report DataSource can you explain more how to find that ? is another way to solve this ? because i dont made connection with the Access DB in DataSource Section

Comment: I would recommend making the connect to your database from within the Database Expert of the report.  Exactly how to to this is a difficult question to answer though because there are many different types of connections such as ADO, OLE DB, ODBC, et al.  The correct one to use will be determined by your specific needs and the type of database.  I believe there is only one option though for an Access Database, however, I have no experience with using Crystal Reports with Access.

Comment: thanks for the reply, my last question is: can I connect to my DB without use Database Expert? I mean programmatically

Comment: There is a way if you are using Visual Studio to manage the project.  You create a DataTable as a project resource.  This DataTable should have the same schema as the return from the SQL query in your code here.  Then in the Crystal Report designer you use that project resource to define your database.  The datatable itself provides no data to the report, its just a schema for the data that will bound to the report at runtime so the designer can have the database fields you need when building the report.

Comment: thanks, its work fine : after reading this tutorial [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/walkthrough-creating-a-datatable-in-the-dataset-designer?view=vs-2019) i create a new DataSet File in the project then add new DataTable then add new columns and add it in my crystal reports and automatically receive the records from the query from the code